# Proving to YouTube that a video is Public Domain: on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Would this question be on-topic here?

http://yro.slashdot.org/story/15/08/16/191215/ask-slashdot-how-to-prove-a-work-is-public-domain

The asker uploaded a very old video to YouTube claiming it is public domain, and YouTube asks him for a "proof" that it is public domain, refusing a simple explanation.

While it is about law, the question is also borderline technical (although it would probably not be on-topic on any other Stackexchange site).

Comment: I think it's worth posting.  I did a quick pass through the links and found an interesting -- and certainly questionable in light of subsequent copyright law -- claim in the 2008 book *Superman Vs. Hollywood* about the rights.